# Check for the string in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am having an array of objects -

```
[{ name: "Thing0", price: "0" }, { name: "Thing1", price: "1" }, { name: "Thing2", price: "2" }]
```

I want to know, if I could search, in the array, for a string, then return that object. 
For example: I want to search for `Thi`. It should return all the objects whose `name` starting or having the letters - 'Thi'.  
Is it possible ? 
Thanks

Comment: what have you tried yet?

Comment: You can basically filter the array, Ex: `arr.filter(x => x.name.contains("Thi"))`. (arr is your array in this example)

Comment: contains has been replaced by 'includes'.

Comment: yes it is possible @mnh 
first match the string and then filter it
`arr.filter(x => Object.keys(x).some(k => x[k].includes("Thi")))`

Comment: Thanks ! This worked -> `const result = array.filter((x) => x.name.includes("Thi"));`